# Radio input element in custom Angular2/5 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular 5 and have a custom component with radio button inside. I use Reactive controls and bind the radio button to the `FormControl`. After putting radio control into the custom component, it stopped setting the `value` of bind `FormControl`.

Here is the usage of custom component:

```
    <ui-options [name]="'gender'"
                    [options]="['m', 'f']"
                    [formControl]="sex" ngDefaultControl
    ></ui-options>
```

`sex` is `FormControl` defined in the `.ts`:

```
sex: FormControl = new FormControl(null, {
    validators: Validators.required, updateOn: 'blur'
});
```

As you see, there is no `form` tag, and that's why I do we use `formControl` binding and not `formControlName`. Just for the record, we have other similar custom controls and they work for e.g. input fields.

#### component

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let op of options">
    <input type="radio" id="{{ name + '-' + op }}" name="{{ name }}" [formControl]="formControl" value="{{ op }}">
    <label for="{{ name + '-' + op }}">{{ label + op }}</label>
  </ng-container>
```

The component is mapped to simple fields:

```
export class UiOptionsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() options: string[];
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() formControl: FormControl;
...
```

#### issue

When I click on the label, the radio does change its status - it gets checked or unchecked, I can style buttons with this state etc: everything works fine.

However, the `FormControl` does not change the `value`! When I put this radio buttons outside of the custom component, everything works.

#### my solution

My only solution was to add a click handler on the label that sets the value:

```
<label for="{{ name + '-' + op }}" (click)="formControl.setValue(op)">{{ label + op }}</label>
```

Now everything works.

My question is: why this does not work out of the box? Why I have to add a click handler?

### EDIT

I have created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/option-issue). Problem is that is working, and my code is still NOT working :(

Comment: does your form have a name? and under that name is there a property for sex? and does that value change?

Comment: There is not form tag, thats why I do use formControl and not formControlName. Other components made like this works.

Comment: is there anyway to access the form control from the component?

Comment: @floor I can access the form control from the component, as I am passing it as an argument named `formControl`. So my control `sex` is passed to the component as `formControl` (the name).

Comment: so the value of the form control 'sex' never changes? is it possible for you to add a button with a test function which when called just console logs the contexts of sex, make it a component property this.sex and see if its value changes after you select the radio button and click your test button or if sex is a property of a form builder can you access it this.formBuilderName.sex.value?

Comment: @floor value of `sex` never is set when in custom control. I have not tried using `this.formBuilder.sex` - I wonder why would I, since this works outside of the custom control.

Comment: @floor Made an example (see edit), but it is working so I can't reproduce the issue.